# Regex to validate the alpha numeric which optionally include the hypen or space

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Validate the given string which includes the alphanumeric of the length either 6 or 7 (includes space or hyphen only once)

the input string length is either 6 or 7 characters if includes a hyphen or space its length should be 7.
Only one space or Hyphen is allowed as a max

Note: the Hyphen or Space is any place in the string and in the below example given few

```
ex: 
A12B3C    -> Valid 
ACB1234   -> Valid
123H67J   -> Valid
ABC-123   -> Valid
ANV 123   -> Valid 
ABV-12345 -> Not Valid 
ABC 1234  -> Not Valid 
ABC-12    -> NOT Valid
ABC 12    -> Not Valid
ABV--35 -> Not Valid
AV- 345 -> Not Valid  
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid
```

```
Regex: ^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=.{7}$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:[- ][0-9A-Z]+)?$

failed the cases like ANV123 as its expected 7 characters
```

Comment: Does this not suit your needs? `[A-Z0-9\-\s]{6,7}`

Comment: Hi @Aggragoth, it failed the cases like below 97 995 this is not Valid but it's allowed as its length is 6 which includes space  https://regex101.com/r/RLrabZ/1 
if including space or hyphen length should be 7. if not included the length of either 6 or 7.

Comment: Then use the following: `^[A-Z0-9\-\s]{7}$|^[A-Z0-9]{6,7}$`

Comment: Thanks, @Aggragoth, it's working as expected but in one case it failed as it accepted the space or hyphen as the first or last character but space or hyphen should not be the first or last character https://regex101.com/r/sm4od3/1

Comment: Please be careful to outline these requirements in your description. Your note does not make that clear; in-fact, it implies the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution as discussed in the comments of your main post.

```
^[A-Z0-9]{6,7}$|(?=^.{7}$)^[A-Z0-9]+[- ]?[A-Z0-9]+$
```

When asking a question, please be sure to outline **all** of your requirements. Its very hard for people to give a correct solution to questions that they don't know the full context of.

Comment: Thanks, @Aggragoth, will update the all details clearly. Sorry for the inconvenience to understand the requirement the last one the space or hyphen max is the only one to allow https://regex101.com/r/5Ot9FF/1 here accepted more than once and both hyphen and space are not allowed either one is allowed https://regex101.com/r/4uhcO4/1 this is not a valid one.

Comment: example: 
`A12B3C    -> Valid 
ACB1234   -> Valid
123H67J   -> Valid
ABC-123   -> Valid
ANV 123   -> Valid 
ABV-12345 -> Not Valid 
ABC 1234  -> Not Valid 
ABC-12    -> NOT Valid
ABC 12    -> Not Valid
ABV--35 -> Not Valid
AV- 345 -> Not Valid  
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV- 124 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid 
AV-12 5 -> Not Valid 
`

Comment: `^[A-Z0-9]{6,7}$|^(?![^0-9A-Z]*([0-9A-Z])(?:[^0-9A-Z]*\1)+[^0-9A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^0-9A-Z]*[0-9A-Z]){6}[^0-9A-Z]*$)[0-9A-Z]+(?:(-| )[0-9A-Z]+)?$`
above regex working as expected

Comment: @HarinathaReddy please see refined solution

Comment: one case failing here as its not allowed if all characters are the same like AAAAAA or 1111111 or 1111-11 or AAAA AA it should not be allowed because all are the same characters but it's allowed now.

1111-11 not Valid 
AAAAAA Not Valid
AAAAAAB   Valid
11111 1    Not Valid

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your examples, it sounds like what you want is:

- Three alphabetic characters `[A-Z]{3}`
- An optional space or hyphen `[ -]?`
- Three or four digits `[0-9]{3,4}`

Which looks like this, with the beginning and end of string anchors.

```
^[A-Z]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3,4}$
```

Comment: Hi @Andy Lester, it's a combination of alphanumeric not like alpha follows numeric it is like ABCDEF as well valid and 1234567 also valid, 123A34 or A1BN435 also valid.

The hyphen and space might come any place in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is functional code with test input based on your requirement to have 6 or 7 alphanumeric chars, or a pattern of 7 chars where all but one are alphanumeric chars with one interspersed space or dash. In addition, do not allow a pattern of all the same char:

```js
const input = [
  'A12B3C',
  'ACB1234',
  '123H67J',
  'ABC-123',
  'ANV 123',
  'ABV-12345',
  'ABC 1234',
  'ABC-12',
  'ABC 12',
  'ABV--35',
  'AV- 345',
  'AV- 124',
  'AV- 124',
  'AV-12',
  'AV-12',
  'AAAAAA',
  '1111111',
  '1111-11',
  '1112-11',
  'AAAA AA'
];
const re = /^(?:(?!^(.)\1+$)[A-Za-z0-9]{6,7}|(?=^.{7}$)(?!^(.)\2*[ -]\2+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+[ -][A-Za-z0-9]+)$/;

input.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + re.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
A12B3C => true
ACB1234 => true
123H67J => true
ABC-123 => true
ANV 123 => true
ABV-12345 => false
ABC 1234 => false
ABC-12 => false
ABC 12 => false
ABV--35 => false
AV- 345 => false
AV- 124 => false
AV- 124 => false
AV-12 => false
AV-12 => false
AAAAAA => false
1111111 => false
1111-11 => false
1112-11 => true
AAAA AA => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `(?:` - non capture group start
- `(?!^(.)\1+$)` - negative lookahead for all the same char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{6,7}` - expect 6 or 7 alphanumeric chars
- `|` - logical OR
- `(?=^.{7}$)` - positive lookahead for exactly 7 chars
- `(?!^(.)\2*[ -]\2+$)` - negative lookahead for all the same char with interspersed space or dash
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+[ -][A-Za-z0-9]+` - expect 1+ alphanumeric chars, a space or dash, followed by 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `)` - non capture group end
- `$` - anchor at end

Comment: @harinatha-reddy: Does that answer your question?